# Which is the equivalent binascii a2b_hex python method to java

Tags: java, python

I have a hex string and in python there is a method a2b_hex from binacii. I want an example to make the same in java.

Comment: What is the functionality you want? Because not everybody knowing Java know python too.

Comment: a2b_hex gets as argument a hex & returns binary data. How can I do that in java. This is somehow the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a hex string to a byte array with [`DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary%28java.lang.String%29):

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

String hexString = "dead";
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString);
```